# Using Custom Pipes in services in angular2

Tags: angular2-pipe

I want to call the my custom pipe inside Injectable service. I checked many threads in stackoverflow. But they talk about using custom pipes inside a component. Can u please help me here, any helpful link will be fine. **Below is my custom pipe file:**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({ name: 'unit' })
export class UnitPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(val,unit, args) {
        if(unit=='Metric') {
            return val * 2;
        }
        else {
            return val * 4;
        }
    }
}
```

And Iam trying to access this pipe in my service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { UnitPipe } from '../pipes/UnitPipe';
@Injectable()
export class SomeService {
    constructor(http: Http, unitPipe: UnitPipe) {
        this.http = http;
        this.unitPipe = unitPipe;
    }
    transformUnit() {
        return this.unitPipe.transform('10', 'Metric');
    }
}
```

I have specified this in **app.module.js**

```
declarations: [UnitPipe],
providers: [UnitPipe]
```

And in my **component.js**, I am calling this service method & just checking the output in console:

```
import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { SomeService } from '../../services/SomeService';
@Component({
})
export class SomeClass implements OnInit {
    constructor(someService: SomeService) {
        this.someService = someService;
    }
    ngOnInit(): void {          
        console.log(this.someService.transformUnit());            
    }
}
```

But Iam getting below error

[image]

**One more thing is, my plan is to call transformUnit method inside my service file 'SomeService', may be onload, where the function definition is present. Any thought on this?**

Thank you.

Comment: Post some code that what you have been tried so it will easy to understand your issue

Comment: Added the code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your pipe transform function expects 3 parameters:

```
transform(val,unit, args) {
  ...
}
```

You're providing only 2 parameters to it:

```
transformUnit() {
    return this.unitPipe.transform('10', 'Metric');
}
```

Best solutions I can suggest is using an *Optional/Default* parameter:

**Optional parameter** - Change `args` to `args?`

OR

**Default parameter** - Change `args` to `args = null` // or some other default value

This will allow you to call the pipe function with 2 params, so no need for code changing in your service.

You can see in this [TypeScirpt-Functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html) link, section called *Optional and Default Parameters* for more details.

Created a simple [StackBlitz DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-using-pipe-in-service) with your code to this in action. Initially you will see the error in `SomeService` file. Just change the pipe `args` param accordingly. refresh the page. The error is gone in `SomeService`.